# Xamarin Forms: Entry with background image

Tags: mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set a background image in a Entry.

I know I can do that using native Android `(android:background="@drawable/myImage" or   mTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImage);).`

Is possible to do that with Xamarin Forms?
I can't find anything in the official documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native control I do not believe has a background image option however, you can extend any control in the Xamarin.Forms namespace and modify it to your needs. If the changes you want to make are beyond what you can accomplish through inheritance perhaps you should Google custom renderers.

Below is an example of extending Grid to make a custom switch with additional binding properties.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace willfunkyouup.CustomControl
{
class CustomSwitch : Grid
{

    public event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> ItemSelected;
    private Button negative;
    private Button positive;

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomSwitch, Object>(t => t.SelectedItem, null, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnSelectedItemChanged);

    public CustomSwitch()
    {

        try
        {
            this.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            this.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

            negative = new Button();
            negative.Text = "No";
            negative.Style = RecoveryConnect_XamForms.AppStyling.Style_Button_Switch;
            negative.Clicked += (o,s) => OnSelectedItemChanged(this, ItemSelected, (int)Classes.Collections.Enums.SelectionStatus.False);

            positive = new Button();
            positive.Text = "Yes";
            positive.Style = RecoveryConnect_XamForms.AppStyling.Style_Button_Switch;
            positive.Clicked += (o, s) => OnSelectedItemChanged(this, ItemSelected, (int)Classes.Collections.Enums.SelectionStatus.True);               

            this.Children.Add(negative, 0,0);
            this.Children.Add(positive, 1,0);
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            willfunkyouup.Classes.Helpers.Helper_ErrorHandling.SendErrorToServer(ex, this.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }

    }

    public Object SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            if (SelectedItem != value)
            {
                base.SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
                InternalUpdateSelected();
            }
        }
    }

    private void InternalUpdateSelected()
    {
        if((int)SelectedItem == (int)Classes.Collections.Enums.SelectionStatus.False)
        {
            negative.BorderColor = willfunkyouup.AppStyling.Color_Selected;
            positive.BorderColor = willfunkyouup.AppStyling.Color_UnSelected;
            positive.Opacity = willfunkyouup.AppStyling.Opaque_High;
        }
        else if ((int)SelectedItem == (int)Classes.Collections.Enums.SelectionStatus.True)
        {
            negative.BorderColor = willfunkyouup.AppStyling.Color_UnSelected;
            negative.Opacity = willfunkyouup.AppStyling.Opaque_High;
            positive.BorderColor = willfunkyouup.AppStyling.Color_Selected;
        }
        else
        {
            negative.BorderColor = willfunkyouup.AppStyling.Color_UnSelected;
            negative.Opacity = willfunkyouup.AppStyling.Opaque_High;
            positive.BorderColor = willfunkyouup.AppStyling.Color_UnSelected;
            positive.Opacity = willfunkyouup.AppStyling.Opaque_High;
        }
    }

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        CustomSwitch boundSwitch = (CustomSwitch)bindable;

        if((int)newValue != (int)Classes.Collections.Enums.SelectionStatus.Unselected)
        {
            boundSwitch.SelectedItem = (int)newValue == (int)Classes.Collections.Enums.SelectionStatus.False ? (int)Classes.Collections.Enums.SelectionStatus.False : (int)Classes.Collections.Enums.SelectionStatus.True;
        }


        if (boundSwitch.ItemSelected != null)
        {
            boundSwitch.ItemSelected(boundSwitch, new SelectedItemChangedEventArgs(newValue));
        }
        boundSwitch.InternalUpdateSelected();
    }

}
```

}